# Will "kubectl create secret" create a string password?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubectl, secret-key

If I use the command like below:

```
kubectl create secret generic mysql-secret --from-literal MYSQL_KEY=11111
```

Should I put the password like a string `"11111"` or number `11111` then after?

Which of the following commands is correct if I have used the above command to create the password?

```
kubectl run -it --rm --image=mysql:8.0 --restart=Never mysql-client -- mysql -h mysql -password="11111"
```

Or

```
kubectl run -it --rm --image=mysql:8.0 --restart=Never mysql-client -- mysql -h mysql -password=11111
```

Comment: Why do you think either one is not correct?

Comment: @P.... Cause I put one of them inside "" and not the other one.